# Simple crawl to website

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website . Will the below code is that efficient to get me the values which I listed

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$target_url = "http://www.phunwa.com/phone/0191/2604233";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
foreach($html->find('Name') as $link){
echo $link."<br />";
}

?>
```

Actaully I am trying to ftech Name , Address and location . COuld anybody please give me any idea on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source code, try getting the contents of the `div` with class `address-tags` then looping through the

tags and echoing the contents.

Try this to start with;

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="address-tags"]')->item(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dom . But are you telling me to do <?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = "http://www.phunwa.com/phone/0191/2604233";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="address-tags"]')->item(0);
foreach($div as $link)
 {
  echo $link->Name."<br />";
  echo $link->Address."<br />";
  echo $link->Location."<br />";
 }

?>

Comment: I'm saying use this as a starting point, you should be able to find the `<p>` elements in `$div` and iterate through them.